# Get associated mouse click from ExpandTree event in SWT

Tags: java, swt

I'm trying to stop the tree from collapsing or expanding when the user double clicks a column on a tree. It should only be allowed if the user clicks on the first column.
[image: checkboxtree]

See, if a user double clicks the checkbox on node2 world1, the tree expands or collapses. I don't want that to happen. My tree needs  SWT.FULL_SELECTION to detect the clicks on each of the columns, so that's not the way to go.

My listener looks like this

```
tree.addTreeListener(new TreeListener() {
        @Override
        public void treeExpanded(TreeEvent e) {
            TreeItem parent = (TreeItem) e.item;
            Point p =  new Point (e.x, e.y);
            int column = CheckboxClickListener.getColumn(p,parent);
            if (column > 0) {
                e.doit = false;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void treeCollapsed(TreeEvent e) {
             TreeItem parent = (TreeItem) e.item;
             Point p =  new Point (e.x, e.y);
             int column = CheckboxClickListener.getColumn(p,parent);
             if (column != 0) {
                 e.doit = false;
             }
        }
    });
```

Problem is, the mouse event that generated the click is not the same as the TreeEvent that expands the tree. Thus, the e.x and e.y are both zero, making my Point detection useless. Listening to the mouse event and maintaining the last x and y to check here in the TreeExpand event seems bug-prone since the user may also expand the tree using the keyboard (thus the x and y may not reflect the user action). I also considered adding a time constraint to check that but seems like a bad way to handle the issue.

How can I detect which mouse event triggered the expand event?

PS: e.doit=false does nothing, even outside the if condition, so help with stopping the tree from expanding/collapsing would be appreciated as well :)

Thank you!

Comment: I am asuming that you did not find a way to prevent expanding/collapsing. I think that you can not prevent any events from happening at the SWT layer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found someone saying this is a bug at this link http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/257325/

The following code stops the tree from expanding on doubleclick but I'm not sure why or what are the side effects.

```
tree.addListener (SWT.MeasureItem, new Listener(){
        @Override
        public void handleEvent(Event event) {}
    });
```

This stops the expanding when doubleclicking ANY column. Clicking on the small arrow at the left of the TreeItem still expands the tree (as it should).